# Regular expression picking all key-value pairs

Tags: php, regex

I have this syntax

```
{{ id, key1:value1; key2:value2; keyn:valuen; }}
```

I need to pick it up so that I have the matches

```
Array (
    [0] => id
    [1] => key1,
    [2] => value1
    ...
)
```

What I currently have is this

```
\{\{\s*(\d+)(?:,\s*(?:(\$\w+)\:(.*?);)+)?\s*\}\}
```

For input

```
{{ 1, $user:John Doe; $dgd:brat; }}
```

It returns

```
matches:
0: (1)
1: ($user)
2: (John Doe; $dgd:brat)
```

I expect

```
matches:
0: (1)
1: ($user)
2: (John Doe)
3: ($dgd)
4: (brat)
```

Thank you.

Comment: Well I'm using PHP but I guess it works the same in all languages?

Comment: @php_nub_qq do you have several instances of this syntax in one string variable?

Comment: @php_nub_qq to be clear, you have input like [this](https://eval.in/181579)?

Comment: @HamZa correct, well the id's will be different, but that doesn't matter in this case

Comment: @php_nub_qq fast answer: you can't do that in one single regex. Well it's [possible like this](http://regex101.com/r/uX9rL1/1) but how will you make the difference between the matches? Of course you could do a loop and check for the IDs. My 2 cents: do it in 2 regexes :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Update #2***

You can go with this regular expression:

```
(?=[^}]*}})(?(?!\w)\s+)\K([$]?[^[:punct:]]+)
```

**[Regex Live demo](http://regex101.com/r/oX8eL4/4)**

[**PHP Live demo**](http://3v4l.org/eKppd)

Comment: It shouldn't split the name on whitespace though.

Answer (score 0):

`/([^\s]+):([^\;]+);/g` will do.

Comment: That won't do since it doesn't capture the id.

Comment: Yes, it does. It shoudl return two different arrays of matches, one with the ids, another with the values.

Comment: Did you check the link you sent? It returns arrays with id and value.

Comment: the **key** and the value, but not the **id**.

Comment: Oh sorry. I missed that. I thought you didn't want the id, only key/value pairs. I guess Revo's answer already covers that.